# Continuous injection of Lipschitz space into $W^{1, \infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let  $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be open, bounded and $C^1$.

I want to show that $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) = C^{0,1}(\overline{\Omega})$, with equivalent norms.

I know that $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow C^{0,1}(\overline{\Omega})$ by using Morrey's theorem. Using the characterization theorem by difference quotients (proposition 9.3 in Brezis), I was able to deduce that $C^{0,1}(\Omega) \subset W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$. However, I'm unable to prove that this injection is continuous. The only issue I'm facing is to prove that $||{\nabla}u||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \leq C [u]_{C^{0,1}(\overline{\Omega})}$, where the right hand side is the Lipschitz semi-norm. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that you proved you have a continuous (by Morrey) bijection between $W^{1,\infty}$ and $C^{0,1}(\bar{\Omega})$. Once you know both are complete Banach spaces (which is not difficult to prove), then the open mapping theorem implies the result you are looking for.

Comment: @Pelota nice solution. Thanks!